# can't have namespace and module import in one file

Tags: typescript

file1.ts

```
namespace test {
    export class AA {}
}
```

file2.ts

```
/// <reference path="file1.ts" />

import * as express from "express"; // without this line it works

namespace test {
    export class BB {
        constructor(a:AA){
              var r = express.Router();
              ...
        }
    }
}
```

If I comment the import line above, the code compiles but express import is missing. If I keep the import, I get

```
enter code hereerror TS2304: Cannot find name 'AA'
```

Any idea how to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

You are mixing so-called "internal" and "external" typescript modules (http://www.typescriptlang.org/Handbook#modules).

"import" keywoard tells compiler that you are using "external" approach. In this case

file1.ts - exports something

```
module test {
    export class AA {}
}

export = test;
```

file2.ts - imports your test module

```
import * as express from "express"; // without this line it works
import { AA } from "test"

module test {
    export class BB {
        constructor(a:AA){
              var r = express.Router();
              ...
        }
    }
}
```

#### Update 1

This works for me in VS2015:

file "test.ts":

```
namespace test {
    export class AA {
        prop: string;
    }
}

export = test;
```

file "consumer.ts":

```
import { AA } from "test";

namespace test {
    export class BB {
        constructor(a: AA) {
            a.prop = "some val";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I just updated my question, I actually ment to use namespace instead of internal modules, sorry for the confusion, any idea how to fix this?

Comment: Can you try "export = test.AA;" in the first file and 'import AA from "test";' in the second one?

Comment: Thanks TSV, Here is the result: export = test.AA; fails as test is not a module